# Storing numbers up to 2 decimal places in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a financial project where I am trying to store amount for my transactions, the price can store up to two decimal, I am trying to choose Schema type for my amount field, I first thought of `Number`with `roundto:2`, another option is to store them in [Number Decimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#numeric-decimal) type.

Now as my prices can only go to upto 2 decimals, so should I stick with default  `Number`with `roundto:2` or there can be some issues where decimals can get rounded of.

Also is there any difference between the number of bytes to store the values in `Number` and in `Number Decimal`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use NumberDecimal, of course.  One should never use regular floating-point numbers for money (they can't represent most values exactly).

Demonstration:

```
db.numbers.insert({fp: 0.1, dec: NumberDecimal('0.1')})
db.numbers.insert({fp: 0.2,  dec: NumberDecimal('0.2')})

db.numbers.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      total_fp: { $sum: "$fp"},
      total_dec: { $sum: "$dec"}
    }
  }
])
// { "_id" : 1, "total_fp" : 0.30000000000000004, "total_dec" : NumberDecimal("0.3") }
```

Comment: What about the storage size for both of them?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur: I have no idea, need to check. But who cares about potential storage size difference when one option is simply not working.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I convert Numberdecimal returned from mongoose to float?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur: if mongoose supports this, it should be covered in their documentation.

Comment: The mongodb shell treats all numbers internally as floating point values. So when you insert a number into a document it is a floating point value. NumberDecimal is a wrapper that treats a floating point value in a specific way. Take a look at the NumberDecimal data type in the MongoDB documentation. They state that it is useful for financial transactions. I do suggest using the NumberDecimal wrapper for all financial transactions.

Comment: @BobCochran: "The mongodb shell treats all numbers internally as floating point values" - except it doesn't. Try `NumberDecimal('1') + NumberDecimal('2')`. For the purposes of JS math, these are not numbers. Just some objects.